# Visualize google quickdraw data

Tags: python

I would like to visualize google's quickdraw data, basically there is a dataset (ndjson) where each line contains one drawing:

```
{ 
"key_id":"5891796615823360",
"word":"nose",
"countrycode":"AE",
"timestamp":"2017-03-01 20:41:36.70725 UTC",
"recognized":true,
"drawing":[[[129,128,129,129,130,130,131,132,132,133,133,133,133,...]]]
}
```

My question is: how can i visualize the drawing? It say that the format of the array is:

```
 [ 
  [  // First stroke 
    [x0, x1, x2, x3, ...],
    [y0, y1, y2, y3, ...],
    [t0, t1, t2, t3, ...]
  ],
  [  // Second stroke
    [x0, x1, x2, x3, ...],
    [y0, y1, y2, y3, ...],
    [t0, t1, t2, t3, ...]
  ],
  ... // Additional strokes
]
```

But still i don't know how to visualize it, i've saw an answer [here](https://github.com/cduck/drawSvg/issues/5), and i don't know that well python, what's jupiter, is there any other way? Thank you in advance

QuickDraw dataset github: https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset

Comment: Why have you tagged three different languages?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't know Python that well you can still make use of the data:

- a drawing is made of of strokes
- each stroke has x,y positions, each (in a separate array)

There are a lot of ways to draw in Python (e.g. [PIL ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.line), [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.polygon), [opencv](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html), etc.)

Having a polyline described as `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],etc.]` is intuitive.
The only catch with the dataset is that the data is formatted as `[[x1,x2,etc.],[y1,y2,etc.]]`

You can easily merge the [x1,x2,...] with [y1,y2,...] data using [zip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)

You can then easily loop through each polyline and render it using a Python API of your choice.

Here's an example using PIL and the cat quickdraw dataset:

```
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# read ndjson lines
lines = open('full_simplified_cat.ndjson','r').readlines()
# grab the first line, JSON parse it and fetch the 'drawing' array
raw_drawing = json.loads(lines[0])['drawing']

print('before',raw_drawing)
# zip x,y coordinates for each point in every polyline
polylines = (zip(polyline[0], polyline[1]) for polyline in raw_drawing)
# notice how the data is shuffled to (x1,y1),(x2,y2) order
print('after',polylines)

# make a new image
pil_img = Image.new("RGB", (240, 270), (255,255,255))
# get a drawing context
d = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_img)
# render each polyline
for polyline in polylines:
    d.line(polyline,fill=(0, 0, 0),width=3)
# display image
pil_img.show()
```

[image: one eyed cat]

Update:

The QuickDraw dataset range you've linked to above includes a link to the [quickdraw python module](https://quickdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that makes it super simple to visualise quickdraw data:

```py
from quickdraw import QuickDrawData

qd = QuickDrawData()

anvil = qd.get_drawing("anvil")
anvil.image.show()
```

The above snippet is the show_image.py examples from https://github.com/martinohanlon/quickdraw_python/tree/master/examples